# How to use two file names in the filemask function for a file type trigger for stored proc

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have a stored procedure that is triggered when a specific file is dropped in an aft location. The file can come in 2 formats "blahfile170001" and "BLAHFILE170001" and I need to ensure that both files trigger and are picked up.

The original code just had "blahfile170001" and we are now receiving it in both formats. I updated it below to include the capital version with ; separating as well as using quotes but to no avail. Newer to sql so not sure what I am missing here. This is for SQL Server 2014 and this is stored as xml data.

```
<Trigger Type="File">
    <FileLocation>\\server\share\dummyfiles\Test\AFT\</FileLocation>
    <FileMask>blahfile170001;BLAHFILE170001</FileMask>
    <Schedule Type="DaysWeek" Days="Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday" />
    <WindowStart>00:05</WindowStart>
    <WindowEnd>23:55</WindowEnd>
</Trigger>
```

Comment: I don't understand how this `<Trigger>` XML relates to SQL Server. Can you show the stored procedure and describe in more detail what "to no avail" means?

Comment: Also what on earth is the filemask function and where does that live? This does not sound like a SQL Server thing at all.

Comment: This snip of code is part of a field named "XMLData" in a table in this database. The function of the XMLData is to create a lockfile and set up a staging table to temporarily hold the data being brought in by the trigger file. I was handed this with very little documentation as the dev that wrote it no longer exists in our company. To no avail simply means that I cannot get it to trigger for 2 different formats. It will only take which ever format I have listed first. It was initially set up as just <FileMask>blahfile170001</FileMask>.

Comment: I just need to ensure that the process is triggered when either blahfile170001 or BLAHFILE170001 is dropped.

Comment: What does "dropped" mean? How does SQL Server know that a file has been "dropped"? Can't the person or app that does this be the trigger?

Comment: So the trigger is a file. A file is sent via AFT to the FileLocation. During the window if a file with a filename that matches the FileMask gets sent to the FileLocation then the file is consumed. The FileMask ensures that this process will only be triggered by a file with that specific filename. I just need it to accept either uppercase or lowercase of the same filename.